# Reactjs nav smooth scrolling and routes

Tags: reactjs, smooth-scrolling

Can someone help me, I designed a custom navbar that when you click on a Link it would smooth scroll to that component. The problem is that when I'm on another route (sample: /shop) and I click on the navbar link it would display an error on "getBoundingClientReact null". I know that the useEffect runs before the html content change but I haven't found any solution yet.

You can check the code here to better understand the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/smooth-scrolling-80npq

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because as the error says `targetSection` is `null`, therefore there can't be called any method on it, `targetSection` is null because in component/ViewPort.js, LINE 33 `const targetSection = document.querySelector("#" + targetId);`, you assign `null` to `targetSection` because there is not any element with id equal to `targetId`.

This is correct, because when you are on path `/shop`, React renders your `ShopScreen` component and that component does not contain any element with the ids that are on `HomeScreen`. You need to call your `SmoothScroll` after the redirecting to `/`, not before.

**EDIT**: As a convenient **solution**, I suggest replacing `<Link>` with `<HashLink>` component from `react-router-hash-link` https://github.com/rafgraph/react-router-hash-link in combination with css `scroll-behavior: smooth` property. This way you won't need to call `SmoothScroll` at all and the code will be more straightforward.

Comment: How do I first redirect before calling the function? I created the SmoothScroll so that I could modify how fast it scroll down or up and its a reference if I create a website using other frameworks.
I also consider it as a practice not relying to much on libraries, but I would look it up

Comment: The problem is that you are looking for elements that are not in the document at the time of the `SmoothScroll` execution. You could redirect and put the hash fragment of the section you want to scroll to as a prop to `HomeScreen`  and handle scrolling in that component after it's mounted into DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Incase of someone searching for the same problem as I do. I fixed it by adding a `setTimeOut` if the user is on another page.

Feel free to check this link. I also modified it so that it has less codes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/smooth-scrolling-80npq